# Setting $("#x").innerHTML does not change element

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to set the value of an H2 element, but the value never changes. When I click on a letter (a, b, c, etc...) on my web page, I try to update the H2 value, like this:

```
function GetEntries(firstLetter) {
    $('#letterChosen').innerHTML = firstLetter;
}
```

And here is the H2 element.

```
<h2 id="letterChosen" class="results">Results</h2>
```

I've tried a few things, and the innerHTML property was my last attempt. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Note, the parameter firstLetter actually has a value, so that isn't the problem.

Comment: Remember to be precise when asking questions.

Comment: @pst I've struggled with your comment. I would normally agree with your change of my title, but my original title is how I was searching in google, and therefore more likely to be how others serach. Anyway, I don't feel strongly about it, and your change is more precise indeed. Thanks.

Comment: The original title is why I voted as "Too Localized". Your "search attempts" were not related to the problem at all; consider saying "Car Hot" to an auto mechanic - what is he/she to think? And, would this *really* make a good search query? Please try to make the title reflect the actual refined problem. (Also, SO answers/questions are indexed/searched, so no point trying to SEO-ize the title, it is for human consumption these days.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById('letterChosen').innerHTML = firstLetter;
```

Or better yet:

```
document.getElementById('letterChosen').firstChild.nodeValue = firstLetter;
```

---

By using jQuery's `$('#letterChosen')`, you are getting a jQuery object, not the element itself. You can access the element by adding `[0]` on the end (so `$('#letterChosen')[0]`) but in this case it's actually kinda stupid to use jQuery when there's a perfectly good native method.

Comment: +1, but I like the shorter version given by Joseph. Thank you!

Comment: You should not use Joseph's answer without reading and understanding [some of the reasons](http://vanilla-js.com/) why I advised plain JavaScript over jQuery.

Comment: That's interesting. It basically comes down to speed, right? In the section Retrieve DOM element by ID, Vanilla JS is 35 times faster than jQuery. My first response is to say that my app is so small that it doesn't really matter, however, it's almost always good to "do the right thing," so you're used to doing it when it really does matter.

Comment: Why is your second example "better yet?"

Comment: The second example manipulates DOM nodes, which is extremely cheap compared to parsing a string, extracting HTML, building a new DOM tree and replacing the existing DOM tree with it (which is the process `innerHTML` follows)

Answer (score 2):

Because `innerHTML` is not a jQuery method. It's actually native. Try `.html()`

```
$('#letterChosen').html(firstLetter);
```

Comment: Perfect. This is why SO rocks. Thank you!